# How to use SCD30 with ESP8266?

Tags: arduino, sensor, esp8266, ide, gas-sensor

I'd like to use a SCD30 sensor connected to ESP8266. I know it's possible to use for example [Adafruit library to connect SCD's to Arduino](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-scd30/arduino):

```
// Basic demo for readings from Adafruit SCD30
#include <Adafruit_SCD30.h>

Adafruit_SCD30  scd30;


void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) delay(10);     // will pause Zero, Leonardo, etc until serial console opens

  Serial.println("Adafruit SCD30 test!");

  // Try to initialize!
  if (!scd30.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Failed to find SCD30 chip");
    while (1) { delay(10); }
  }
  Serial.println("SCD30 Found!");


  // if (!scd30.setMeasurementInterval(10)){
  //   Serial.println("Failed to set measurement interval");
  //   while(1){ delay(10);}
  // }
  Serial.print("Measurement Interval: "); 
  Serial.print(scd30.getMeasurementInterval()); 
  Serial.println(" seconds");
}

void loop() {
  if (scd30.dataReady()){
    Serial.println("Data available!");

    if (!scd30.read()){ Serial.println("Error reading sensor data"); return; }

    Serial.print("Temperature: ");
    Serial.print(scd30.temperature);
    Serial.println(" degrees C");
    
    Serial.print("Relative Humidity: ");
    Serial.print(scd30.relative_humidity);
    Serial.println(" %");
    
    Serial.print("CO2: ");
    Serial.print(scd30.CO2, 3);
    Serial.println(" ppm");
    Serial.println("");
  } else {
    //Serial.println("No data");
  }

  delay(100);
}
```

But it requires SDL and SDA pins, which my ESP doesn't have. And this code at least doesn't allow changing the connection pins. I know that connecting SCD30 and ESP8266 is at the very least possible using YAML format, then you can use regular digital pins. But I'd like to know if it's possible to do it with Arduino code as well.

If SCD30 isn't possible to use this way then how about other air sensors, would the CSS811 work?

Comment: The ESP8266 datasheet appears to show support for I2C. Do you mean a ESP8266 _module_ is being used which doesn't break out the I2C pins to the connectors on the module?

Comment: The [Datasheet Sensirion SCD30 Sensor Module](https://www.sensirion.com/media/documents/4EAF6AF8/61652C3C/Sensirion_CO2_Sensors_SCD30_Datasheet.pdf) says the _digital interface_ can be selected as I2C **or** UART. Is using a UART an option?

Comment: *"You can change what pins are used in the software - for Arduino it's done by passing in the pin numbers in the Wire.begin() function"* - https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?p=87469